# Double-click event on borderless forms

Tags: c#, winforms, double-click, borderless

I created a borderless form and I've been able to activate the form move event through this code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void FASTMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}

private void FASTMain_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to intercept the mouse double-click event on the form as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking for the e.Clicks value:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
  base.OnMouseDown(e);

  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    if (e.Clicks > 1) {
      // do something with double-click
    } else {
      ReleaseCapture();
      SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot